# document.getElementByTagName XML

Tags: xml, getelementsbytagname

I have a handler which returns me a XML Request as an alert() with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <gml:TimePeriod xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <gml:beginPosition>2011-10-18T15:15:00.000+02:00</gml:beginPosition>
  <gml:endPosition>2014-11-23T14:45:00.000+01:00</gml:endPosition>
  </gml:TimePeriod>
```

The handler looks like that:

```
function handler(request) {
  alert(request.responseText);  
};
```

Now I would like parse the xml tag “beginPosition” to an array.
I used the following code within the handler:

```
function handler(request) {
  alert(request.responseText);  
  var xmlDoc = request.responseXML;

  timeArray = xmlDoc.getElementByTagName('beginPosition').value= new Date(request.responseText).toTimeString();
  console.log(timeArray);
};

var timeArray;
alert(timeArray);
```

Finally I got the error message:
TypeError: xmlDoc.getElementByTagName is not a function

How can I parse the date value in that array from the xml request?

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one element of a given tag name in a document, so the method you are looking for is `getElementsByTagName` (plural) which returns a NodeList (which is like an array).

Comment: Ok, beside this typing error I got the message "invalid date". And I am not sure about the xmlDoc variable. Still I do not get the a correct date in that array.

Comment: I solved it see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168108/no-xmldocument-from-openlayers-request-post/27172325#27172325